# Scheduler: failed to execute scheduled job: AsyncApexJobObject, reason: You have exceeded the maximum number (100) of Apex scheduled jobs

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, asyncapexjob

I have implemented is a Schedulable Interfaced class, which I have scheduled to run every day at a certain time. In a nutshell, it runs a for-loop inside which, I use: system.scheduleBatch method to schedule an apex batch to run after 50 minutes intervals.

I have analyzed my live-production data and found that the for loop shouldn't have more than 10-12 iterations, on average, which means about 10-12 system.scheduleBatch runs to schedule batch executions, 50 minutes apart from each other.

I am although seeing this issue: *You have exceeded the maximum number (100) of Apex scheduled jobs* when my schedulable class (below) runs on its time.

I am confused on how to resolve this. Should I refrain from using system.scheduleBatch and just use database.execute ? So these 10-12 batches runs sequentially without consuming my scheduled jobs limit ? What should be the ideal approach to implement such an ask?

```
public class SM_Exit_D8AssignmentJobsDispatcher implements Schedulable  { 
    public void execute(SchedulableContext SC){ 
        
        if(test.isRunningTest()){
            SMsForAutoExit = [SELECT Id,ManagerId FROM USER WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()];
        }else{
            SMsForAutoExit = [SELECT Id,ManagerId FROM USER WHERE SM_Exited_by_Director__c = false 
                          AND Inactive_Sales_Manager__c = true AND SM_Exit_Date__c =: N_DAYS_BEFORE_TODAY];
        }
        
        for(User exited_sm : SMsForAutoExit){
            SM_Exit_AutoJobModel exit_job = new SM_Exit_AutoJobModel();
            exit_job.EXITED_SM = exited_sm.Id;
            exit_job.EXITED_SM_TL = exited_sm.ManagerId;   /*For Exit Dump Record Only*/
            exit_job.SELECTED_SMS = managerIdVsActiveCohort.get(exited_sm.ManagerId);
            ExitJobList.add(exit_job);          
            autoExitedSMIds.add(exited_sm.Id);          /*User record keeping*/
        }
        
        if(ExitJobList.size()>0){
            autoschedulejobs(ExitJobList);
        }
        
        /*User Record Keeping*/
        for(String exitedSMId : autoExitedSMIds){
            autoExitedsSMs.add(new USER(Id = exitedSMId, SM_Exited_Automatically__c = true));
        }
        if(autoExitedsSMs.size()>0){
            Database.update(autoExitedsSMs);
        }
            
    }
    
    /*Private method to schedule exit jobs. First job is scheduled at 5 minutes from execution time, 
    and subsequent jobs after every 50 minutes*/
    
    private void autoschedulejobs(List<SM_Exit_AutoJobModel> autoJobsList){
        Integer JOB_NUMBER = 1;
        Integer minutesFromNow = 5;
        
        if(autoJobsList.size()>0){
            for(SM_Exit_AutoJobModel exitjob : autoJobsList){ 
                system.scheduleBatch(new ReassignOpportunitiesFromExitedSMBatch(exitjob.EXITED_SM,exitjob.SELECTED_SMS,exitjob.EXITED_SM_TL,false,true,null), 'SM_Exit_AutoAssignment Job: '+JOB_NUMBER, minutesFromNow);
                minutesFromNow = minutesFromNow + 50;
                JOB_NUMBER++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    private class SM_Exit_AutoJobModel{
        String EXITED_SM;
        String EXITED_SM_TL;
        List<String> SELECTED_SMS;
    }
}
```

Comment: does the `ReassignOpportunitiesFromExitedSMBatch` use `System.abortJob` to clean up?

Comment: @cropredy: no it does not, could this be an issue? if yes, how?

Comment: looking at my code base; all my schedulable's `execute()` end with a `System.abortJob(..)` to clean up `ApexAsyncJob` records. This might help. Also, what is the cron expression used to run `SM_Exit_D8AssignmentJobsDispatcher`?

Also - the jobs may run in parallel depending on how long a given job takes. Usually I have the batchable finish() schedule the next job to avoid this